# Noise in bet kenesset. Sources in Halakha for stopping this

Tags: tefilla, synagogue

If someone is praying in a bet kenesset that let's say is somewhat "chaotic" in its energy... What is the Halakha?

People come in with their phones on loud and throughout the whole tefilla there is notifications pinging the whole time "beep, beep, beep". Sometimes people are on their phones browsing Facebook, noises going off the whole time, etc.

The rabbi is confrontation-averse and never says anything to anyone about it.

I happen to be particularly sensitive to noise. (If people bang tables I stare at them to stop etc). Noises from outside really bother me, more so than others. I've tried to work on it internally but I struggle to block out the distracting noises.

What is the Halakha as regards these types of things? Is this something to confront offenders about? Should they have their phones on silent? Should I confront them?

Today I confronted someone as it was really bothering me. He did end up putting his phone on silent but not before mouthing off to me about "who are you, the religious police?!" etc. I felt bad but I also feel like it's a Hutzpah for people to just think that their 'right' to have their phones on loud trumps others' rights to pray in peace and quiet. Throughout the whole day in the modern world we are bombarded with noise, notifications, pinging, alarms, messages, calls, etc. For the brief time I'm in bet kenesset I don't want that. Is it wrong of me?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya! This site isn't a place for practical halachic guidance, so your question will likely be closed. You are welcome to edit it to be more generalized and less practical and/or to ask a rabbi other than your shul's on what to do. In any case, it's great to have you here.

Comment: Consider switching synagogue...

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! You are 100% right. It is important for the synagogue to be treated with respect and honor. It is also important to pray without being distracted. I would suggest finding a synagogue where people know the proper way to behave.

Comment: You yelling at people is unlikely to change anything. You can talk to the rabbi, who will probably shrug that there's not much he can do either. Please do not let random Internet strangers (including me) encourage you to make more useless fights. Find another synagogue if you can. If not, it may be worth having a discussion with your rabbi if praying at home on weekdays is the better move. Don't try to phrase this as "the halacha says they are all wrong"; phrase this as "what do *I* need to do to make sure *I* can talk to God?"

Comment: Shalom is so so important. Love for your fellow Jew is so so important. If there's no way to stop them with the phones, and it is making you hate them, run for your life. Hating a Jew is much much worse than not having kavana during prayer. Or stay, and work on finding a way to love them even if they are annoying, try to find a way to don lechaf zechus. If you truly love them, then you can work on teaching them about the proper kavod for Hashem's house of prayer.  You'll be surprised, they will turn into bigger tzaddikim than you can imagine!